# Google Sheets: Have functions create cells if they run into existing data

Tags: google-sheets

This might not be possible, but I was curious if there was a way to make functions like `=FILTER()` and `=UNIQUE()` to create new cells if they run into data they cannot overwrite? I have a database composed of items from multiple sheets and as of right now I'm only able to use one filter function because of the nature of what I'm doing. Would be most convenient if something like this does exist, but a rather extensive round of google searching turned up no results

Answer (score 2):

no, this is not possible, however, if your formulae are of the same size you can stack them up so if your dataset will grow then new rows should be auto-added. for example, if you have `FILTER` that outputs 3 columns & 5 rows today but tomorrow it will output 10 rows and under it you got `UNIQUE` that also outputs 3 columns & n rows, then you can do:

```
={FILTER(A:C, A:A<>""); {"","",""}; UNIQUE(D:F)}
```

---

`{"","",""}` acts as empty row as separator

Comment: I ended up coming up with a solution earlier this morning, `=UNIQUE({A:A;B;B,...})` It serves the purpose, but there's blank spots in the columns so I get an empty cell between each columns data, there a way around that? To be more specific, can I make the `=UNIQUE()` ignore empty cells?

Comment: `=unique(filter(A:A,A:A<>""))` did the trick